# Vb.net command not working but works in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following code in VB.NET :

```
  Try
        konneksie.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = " Update ontledings " &
                " set SlaagB = CASE WHEN LaasteSuiker >= SuikerParsreels THEN 'JA'  " &
                " WHEN LaasteSuiker < SuikerParsreels And LaasteSuiker > 0 THEN 'NEE'  " &
                " WHEN LAST Is NULL THEN 'GEEN' " &
                " End "

        COMMAND = New SqlCommand(Query, konneksie)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Toets of aan SUIKER parsreels voltooi in skedulering EN ontledings")
        konneksie.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
    End Try
    konneksie.Close()
```

It shows results of NULL. However when I run the following query in SQL it works fine :

```
      Update ontledings 
                 set SlaagB = CASE WHEN LaasteSuiker >= SuikerParsreels THEN 'JA'  
                 WHEN LaasteSuiker < SuikerParsreels And LaasteSuiker > 0 THEN 'NEE' 
                 WHEN LAST Is NULL THEN 'GEEN' 
                 End
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're making a SQL update, why would you need to return data? If you want to return data then you need to be making a select as well. And don't you need to be using `ExecuteNonQuery()` to execute the query if it's just an update statement

Comment: Thank you for replying Andrew. What do you mean wit "return data"?

Comment: So what are you trying to do? You are performing a SQL update statement which does not return any records from your database so ExecuteReader will always be null.

Comment: I am trying to update my database.

Comment: As long as execution doesn't make it into the catch block, you have succeeded in the update.  As Andrew noted, ExecuteNonQuery is the way to go here.  COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery means to run a SQL statement that isn't a question (INSERT, UPDATE).  ExecuteReader is for questions (SELECT statements).

Comment: No the execution does not go into the catch block and no the update does not seem to succeed. Database table gives "NULL" values. Strangely the same code worked fine yesterday, but not today. Also changing the code to COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()  instead of READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader does not make a difference

Comment: Also if use exactly the same code for updating another database table the code works perfectly.

Comment: @Gideon Are you trying to say that once you perform the update and then run a select you receive NULL?